# handling multiple selected rows at UItableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to get the textLabels of all the selected Rows, but I don’t know how to do that searched about it but didn’t get any help from that so I tried something on my own but its not working as I want it to be, I thought creating an array and sorting the textLabels of selected cells would work for it (yeah its working fine) but when am deselecting a cell  I want to remove that particular cell’s textLabel from my array, if anybody knows how to do that then please tell me

here’s my code -

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    if (cell?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark){

        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None;
        getTheChannelNames.removeAtIndex(getTheChannelNames.count - 1)



        print(getTheChannelNames.count)
           print(getTheChannelNames)



    }else{
        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark;
        _ = self.ChannelList[indexPath.row]

        if (cell?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark){


                getTheChannelNames.append((cell?.textLabel?.text)!)
            print(getTheChannelNames.count)
               print(getTheChannelNames)
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Rather that storing the text, you should simply store a set of selected rows - the text you can easily get from your data model.  You can use an `NSMutableIndexSet` to store the selection state

Comment: okay so `NSMutablwIndexSet` is what i need for  getting multiple values ? thanks for answering :)

Comment: It is a good data structure to use to store indicies (rows) and you can quickly check to see if a given index is in the set; In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you can check if the row is already in the set; if it isn't add it, if it is remove it.  In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can check the set to see if you should add or remove the checkmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways to handle this issue. First of all, it is of extreme importance for you to keep track of the indexPath of the text label that was selected. By doing so you avoid having to sort. A dictionary is better suited for this task.

```
var selectedTextLabels = [NSIndexPath: String]()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    if let text = cell.textLabel?.text {
        selectedTextLabels[indexPath] = text
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    cell.accessoryType = .None
    selectedTextLabels[indexPath] = nil
}
```

If a cell is selected, the text label is added to the dictionary. On the contrary, when it gets deselected it is removed from the dictionary.

The second solution is a method which returns all the selected text labels:

```
func selectedTextLabels() -> [String]? {
    return self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.flatMap {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath($0)!
        return cell.textLabel?.text
    }
}
```

It takes all the selected index paths and gets the text labels for each one.